# matplotlib colored segment of a function plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, polygon

I wonder if there is a more elegant way to draw the polygon in below code, or with a special plot function or parameter ?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm
x = np.linspace(-4,4,150)
# plot density with shaded area showing Pr(-2 <= x <= 1)
lb = -2
ub = 1
d=norm.pdf(x)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.plot(x, d)
### can this be done more elegantly ###
sx = np.linespace(lb,ub,100)
sd = norm.pdf(sx)
sx = [lb] + sx + [ub]
sd = [0] + list(sd) + [0]
xy = np.transpose(np.array([sx, sd]))
pgon = plt.Polygon(xy, color='b')
#######################################
ax.add_patch(pgon)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for [plt.fill_between](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm
x = np.linspace(-4,4,150)
# plot density with shaded area showing Pr(-2 <= x <= 1)
lb = -2
ub = 1
d = norm.pdf(x)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.plot(x, d)

idx = np.searchsorted(x,[lb,ub])
sx = x[idx[0]:idx[1]]
sd = d[idx[0]:idx[1]]
plt.fill_between(sx, sd, 0, color = 'b')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I changed the way `sx` and `sd` are computed. It is more efficient to slice `x` and `d` than it is to recompute `norm.pdf`. Maybe it is not so important in this case, but I think it is better style (and maybe important if the computation were more expensive).